# Two-way binding in AvalonEdit doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, avalonedit

I have used AvalonEdit in my project that is based on WPF and MVVM.
After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344367/making-avalonedit-mvvm-compatible) I created the following class:

```
public class MvvmTextEditor : TextEditor, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static DependencyProperty DocumentTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DocumentText", 
                                    typeof(string), typeof(MvvmTextEditor),
        new PropertyMetadata((obj, args) =>
        {
            MvvmTextEditor target = (MvvmTextEditor)obj;
            target.DocumentText = (string)args.NewValue;
        })
    );

    public string DocumentText
    {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set { base.Text = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("DocumentText");
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

and used the following XAML to use this control:

```
<avalonedit:MvvmTextEditor x:Name="xmlMessage">
   <avalonedit:MvvmTextEditor.DocumentText>
      <Binding Path ="MessageXml" Mode="TwoWay" 
               UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:XMLMessageValidationRule />
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
   </avalonedit:MvvmTextEditor.DocumentText>
</avalonedit:MvvmTextEditor>
```

but the binding works `OneWay` and doesn't update my string property nor run validation rule.

How can I fix binding to work as expected `TwoWay`?

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly how you got this working? I have asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964176/two-way-binding-to-avalonedit-document-text-using-mvvm?noredirect=1#comment28010773_18964176)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPF bindings do not use your `DocumentText` property; instead they access the underlying value of the dependency property directly.

Your `OnTextChanged` method doesn't actually change the value of the underlying dependency property. You will need to copy the value from `base.Text` into the dependency property on every change:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    SetCurrentValue(DocumentTextProperty, base.Text);
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
}
```

This issue would be easier to see if you followed the correct pattern for implementing `DependencyProperty`: The `DocumentText` property should use the `GetValue`/`SetValue` methods, and not access a different backing store.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply - I has helped. I am however confused about how to use the `GetValue`/`SetValue` in the code above for `MvvmTextEditor` class? It seem that it is not compatible with the current implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Even using GetValue and SetValue you can't get the TextProperty to update the binded when the text change, so Daniel answer must be followed anyway.

I did change a bit to make it more intuitive to the end user having to use the Text as normal and dependecy mode:

```
    public new string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    internal string baseText { get { return base.Text; } set { base.Text = value; } }

    public static DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MvvmTextEditor),
        // binding changed callback: set value of underlying property
        new PropertyMetadata((obj, args) =>
        {
            MvvmTextEditor target = (MvvmTextEditor)obj;
            if(target.baseText != (string)args.NewValue)    //avoid undo stack overflow
                target.baseText = (string)args.NewValue;
        })
    );

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {            
        SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, baseText);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
```

I had to check if the same text was already there to avoid the undo stack engine exception. Also performance wise is a good deal.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code based on the answers above with slight modifications, as binding was not working for me both ways. The content below should allow to bind two ways.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyContent", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextEditor), new PropertyMetadata("", OnMyContentChanged));

    private static void OnMyContentChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (MyTextEditor)sender;
        if (string.Compare(control.MyContent, e.NewValue.ToString()) != 0)
        {
            //avoid undo stack overflow
            control.MyContent = e.NewValue.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string MyContent
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set { Text = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        SetCurrentValue(MyContentProperty, Text);
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
```