# Invoke search in Avalon Editor using Button click

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I am using AvalonEditor inside a window dialog(WPF). Window dialog host TextEditor control. I have Find button explicit on Window. On click of Button, Search should work inside TextEditor. Can you please suggest how to bind Button Find to invoke TextEditor Search.

Currently, I have edited the TextEditor constructor to install the SearchPanel. And when Ctrl + F is pressed inside TextEditor, default search dialog appears.
I want the same thing to work on Button click, but using MVVM approach.

Please suggest.

WPF XAML code

```
<Window>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Name="FindButton" Content="Find" Margin="2" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonFooter_Style}" >
                <Button.CommandBindings>
                    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Find" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute">
                    </CommandBinding>
                </Button.CommandBindings>
            </Button>            
        <avalonEdit:TextEditor Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="textEditor"
                FontFamily="Consolas"
                FontSize="10pt"                                
                SyntaxHighlighting="XML" ShowLineNumbers="True" >
        </avalonEdit:TextEditor>
</Window>
```

TextEditor.cs class constructor already been edited

```
public TextEditor() : this(new TextArea())
    {
        Search.SearchPanel.Install(this.TextArea);
    }
```

to have find feature enabled on pressing Ctrl + F

Now I want Find button to invoke Search feature without pressing Ctrl + F.

-Thanks

Comment: show us the code. According to docs, there are commands available for binding to your button.

Comment: Hi, I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

In code behind...

create a member:

```
private readonly SearchPanel searchPanel;
```

in your constructor, or in any block that suits your needs (it needs to happen only once):

```
searchPanel = SearchPanel.Install(textEditor);
```

and then in the event handling code:

```
        searchPanel.SearchPattern = "eg. your selected text";
        searchPanel.Open();
        searchPanel.Reactivate();;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399756/5041912
you can also add a Boolean DependencyProperty that can be set in the ViewModel and toggled by a button click

in the View Model:

```
private bool _openSearchPanel;
public bool OpenSearchPanel { get => _openSearchPanel; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _openSearchPanel, value); }

private void OpenSearchPanelCmd()
{
    OpenSearchPanel = !OpenSearchPanel;
}
```

in the MvvmTextEditor:

```
public bool OpenSearchPanel
{
     set
     {
         this.searchPanel.Open();
         this.searchPanel.Reactivate();
     }
}
```

and in the View:

```
<local:MvvmTextEditor OpenSearchPanel="{Binding DataContext.OpenSearchPanel, ElementName=xxxx}"
```

[Open AvalonEdit SearchPanel with a button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGl5s.gif)